# JavaScript: text element returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, selector, element

I'm trying to retrieve the entered text in each textbox, by querying and looping through by ID tag.

But when I print what I have retrieved it outputs "undefined".

Looks like your post is mostly code:

```
</head>
  <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <font color=black size=+3>Modifying Sentiment</font>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Text to Save:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          Add positive adjective:
          <img Adjective src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2776/android_icons/96/ic_question_mark.png" alt="question" title="Adjective: is a word naming an attribute of a noun, such as sweet, red, or technical."
            width=20 />
          <br>
          <textarea cols=40 rows=3 id="textbox" ></textarea>
          <textarea id="textbox" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
        <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button>
        <td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function saveTextAsFile(){
        var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('textbox');
        var textToWrite;
        for(var i in textBoxes){
          textToWrite = textBoxes[i].value;
          window.alert(textToWrite);
        }
        var textToWrite = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
        var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: first: `document.querySelectorAll('textbox');` should be `document.querySelectorAll('#textbox');`

Comment: You can't re-use "id" values. They need to be unique for each element.

Comment: second: as @Pointy introduced every `textarea ` should have a different id and a short describing class so that you can convert `document.querySelectorAll('textbox');` to `document.querySelectorAll('textbox.my-class');`

Comment: What will the # do ?
Can you explain what you mean about a "short describing class"  @morels

Comment: add a class attribute to all the textbox you want to call a callback on. the `#` selector means that the text following is an id. pls see [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your javascript to point to `textarea` instead of `textbox`.
I also modified your for loop as I was getting additional outputs in the console.  I also changed your `alert` to a `console.log` as jsbin was throwing an error of possible endless loop.
Try this:

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    var textToWrite;
    for(var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; ++i){
      textToWrite = textBoxes[i].value;
      console.log(textToWrite);
    }


    textToWrite = document.getElementById("textarea").value;

    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite],{type:'text/plain'});

    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
}
```

Comment: I used the above example along with the ('#textbox'); to fix by problem.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using #textbox as this refers to the ID of the dom elements

Comment: This is more suitable to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually each id value in an html document should be unique. In your HTML code, I can see two `id` parameter with the same value "textbox". Try to change the first to "textbox-1" or whatever make sense to you but don't repeat the same value for id property and it should work.